# What do you call somebody who eats a lot?

Tags: word-meaning

I had read that "glutton" is used for somebody who eats a lot. Is it used commonly or are there  any other words that are more common?

Comment: It largely depends on context, but it's common to call someone who eats a lot and rather sloppily **a pig**.

Comment: Are there any other commonly used words? This may sound a bit derogatory.

Comment: I'd say **big eater** would be another common way to call someone who eats a lot. Come to think of it, yet, another common expression would be **foodie**. A foodie is a person who enjoys eating fancy food. As I said, it all depends on context.

Comment: Could you give an example of the type of sentence that you want to use the word "glutton" in.

Answer (score 3):

"Glutton" is a useful word However, it is a little old-fashioned, it carries a negative connotation. It is someone who *overeats* (and gluttony is one of seven sins). When you want this connotation it is the right word to use.

If you don't want that effect I would just describe:

> Mary eats a lot, but she exercises every day so she never gets fat.

Other words: "Foodies" are people who love good food but don't necessarily eat a lot of it. Foodie is rather casual. A "gourmand" is someone who is extremely (and often excessively) fond of eating and drinking. "Pig" is certainly insulting, but can be heard used as a joke between friends. (I suspect that the term "pig" is even more insulting in other cultures) To gorge is to eat a large amount at one time, so a gorger is a person who will stuff themselves. Again, this would be viewed negatively.

It seems that English speakers tend to view people who eat a lot in a generally negative way. The plain description "she eats a lot" seems to be the only neutral way to say this.

Comment: How about "gorger"? "Foodie" and "gourmand" indicate a more favorable view toward the person and "pig" sounds a downright insult. Can gorger be used for a more neutral tone?

Comment: A gourmand is someone who is extremely (and often excessively) fond of eating and drinking. You're thinking of 'gourmet': someone with refined tastes who enjoys (and knows a lot about) fine food and drink. There is a French cafeteria style restaurant chain called Flunch which had the slogan (translated) "Where the gourmands meet the gourmets". They often have 'come back as many times as you like' offers. http://grammarist.com/usage/gourmet-vs-gourmand/

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought that gourmand and gourmet were synonyms. Much appreciated.

Comment: Would it sound natural if you call someone who habitually overeats a **gourmand** @James K ? E.g. "You're a reall gourmand; you know that it's harmful to your health; so try to cut down on eating**. Does it sound idiomatic and normal usage of the word to you?

Answer (score 0):

*glutton* is the commonest I've heard. Other words that I use include

> *pig, hog, and gourmand*

Please note that the first two words *could be* offensive.

Another word that I can think of is a *stuffer.* [Have a reference:](https://graziadaily.co.uk/life/real-life/stuffers/) It reads...

> *Stuffers purposely overeat to gain weight, posting before and after pictures on the Internet to chart their progress. It's scary stuff...*